# Why is my top level key being altered when I unset an element?

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I am nearing the end of my coding for a plugin which allows an admin to add custom data to the SQL DB 'custom_tokens'. As the plugin allows for multiple 'tokens' I want it ordered as follows ("enu" can be seen as the category of tokens if you will):

```
[enu] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Enumivo
        [contract] => enu.token
        [symbol] => ENU
        [logo] => 
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Eurno
        [contract] => token.eurno
        [symbol] => ENO
        [logo] => 
        )
    )
```

It all works well for saving of the tokens (I have the PHP to check if there is already a token in that category and, if there isn't, create the category. If there is, just append to it.

The problem is with the removal of entries. Prior to making it a nested array it worked fine - the token you selected to remove would be removed and the array would be reshuffled - but now I have added the top level I am running into the following problem: When I remove, for example, "Eurno" it will also rename the upper level key ("enu") to a number. An example of the array after deletion is as follows:

```
[0] => Array (
    [name] => Enumivo
    [contract] => enu.token
    [symbol] => ENU
    [logo] => 
    )
```

The desired result would be:

```
[enu] => Array (
    [name] => Enumivo
    [contract] => enu.token
    [symbol] => ENU
    [logo] => 
    )
```

The code which I feel is problematic is as follows:

```
// Get array //
$cur_tokens = get_option('custom_tokens');

// Set the nest to look in //
$cur_tokens = $cur_tokens['enu'];

// Initialise the loop //
foreach ($cur_tokens as $key => $cur) {

  // Check which item has been selected for deletion //
  if(isset($_POST['token-'.$key])) {

    // Unset it //
    unset($cur_tokens[$key]);

    // Update the database //
    update_option( 'custom_tokens', $cur_tokens );
  }
}
```

Any help is massively appreciated. I have already tried to achieve it by setting the key to null and then doing an array_filter() but returned the same results.

I know it is probably something silly as is always the case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Manipulating the very same array you are looping over inside the loop is a recipe for disaster. Manipulating values only would still be okay, but actually removing elements _while_ you are looping over it, is a big no-no. This should happen the other way around - you should loop over a different array containing the keys you want to remove.

Comment: @misorude ah I see, would you recommend trying to set another variable with the array in?

Comment: Which PHP version you are on? The foreach logic was changed in PHP 7

Comment: @Dharman I'm using 7.2.10

Comment: I would structure the form in a way, that `$_POST['token']` is an array containing the keys only (`name="token[]"` or similar in the HTML code) - then you can loop over _that_, and nuke the elements out of your other array without any interference with the inner workings of the loop.

Comment: @misorude I just gave that a spin and it still appears to do the same :-(. 

I changed my form so that the HTML field is `(name="token[$key]")`, then I changed the PHP as follows:

      `foreach ($arr as $key => $cur) {
        if(isset($_POST['token'][$key])) {
          unset($cur_tokens[$key]);
          update_option( 'custom_tokens', $cur_tokens );
        }
      }`

Comment: What is $arr? I said you should loop directly over `$_POST['token']`.

Comment: Also, what does `update_option` do? Are you sure you want to call that inside the loop already, and not maybe only once, afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `$arr = $_POST['token'];` however it still has the same result.

Comment: @misorude update_option is the wordpress function to allow you to post the result from the admin back-end to the SQL DB.

Comment: @misorude The reason for calling update_option in the loop was that people can select multiple tokens to remove in one go. So for each set item I would like it removed from the DB

Comment: But the only actual data you are passing to that function is the modified $cur_tokens array - so surely that should work as well if you call it after the loop, with the modified array that has more than one item removed …?

Comment: @misorude I think my answer got posted between your comment. Is there anyway for me to mark your comment as the help which got the correct answer?

Comment: @DaFingIs no worries, main thing is you got a solution that works for you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive thanks to all who helped me, especially @misorude!

It was their answer which assisted with solving the problem. It seems the issue was caused by a combination of what Misorude said (editing a loop I am currently in) and defining the sub key in the $cur_tokens variable. I also took the update_options call out of the loop.

The working PHP code is as follows:

```
  $cur_tokens = get_option('custom_tokens');
  if(isset($_POST['token'])) {
  $arr = $_POST['token'];
  foreach ($arr as $key => $cur) {
      unset($cur_tokens['enu'][$key]);
    }
    update_option( 'custom_tokens', $cur_tokens );
  }
```

And the edited HTML is:

```
name="token['.$key.']"
```

As was explained by Misorude, putting the selected tokens in their own array seems to have done the trick.

Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot wrong with the code. It also seems to me that, you are unsetting the wrong array. You need to use foreach twice here to unset the array. Because it's multidimensional. So if you want to make it dissapear you need to actually remove the second key from your array what is in this case 0 or 1.

```
foreach ($cur_tokens as $key => $cur) {
    foreach($cur as $token_key =>$row){

         if(isset($_POST['token-'.$token_key])) {
         unset($row[0]);

    }
  }
}
```

The array will look something like this then:

```
[enu] => Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Eurno
        [contract] => token.eurno
        [symbol] => ENO
        [logo] => 
        )
    )
```

it's a pseudo code, but I hope you'll get the idea.

Comment: if you want to sort it by token key, you need to change the array key on the second level basicly. So the if in my code is kind of useless atm.

Comment: I did change `unset($row[0])` to `unset($row[$token_key])`